# Caption Flashing When Should Not be Present When Using Form.Show

Tags: c#, winforms, flash

This is strange to me - pretty new to Winforms. I do not see an answer on stackoverflow.

I have a form that I am displaying with a Show. It should not have a caption, or so I think since for the `FormBorderStyle` I specified `None`. The caption displays very quickly (e.g. 1/10 second) as a flash, but very annoying and then shows the form as it should. The duration appears to increase with the number of controls in the form. I have tried setting `DoubleBuffered` to `true` for the form.

Ideas appreciated and an explanation if you understand it. It does not seem like the caption should be showing up at all.

Comment: It's too difficult to answer without the code, which reproduces that effect.

Comment: When do you set FormBorderStyle to none? While runtime (e.g. Load/Show-Event) or during design time?

Comment: It is set during design time. Thanks!